# SQL query is not working query

Tags: mysql, sql

Anyone got a clue where is the problem? It must be really just comma or spelling mistake but I am looking at this 5 lines 2 hours and still can not see it maybe someone can see it very quickly.

Error
SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO SalesOrder
(

Customer, ContactName, Phone, Email, BillingAddress1, BillingAddress2, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingCountry, BillingPostalCode, BillingAddressRemarks, ShipToCompanyName, ShippingAddress1, ShippingAddress2, ShippingCity, ShippingState, ShippingCountry, ShippingPostalCode, ShippingAddressRemarks, CurrencyCode, ExchangeRate, PricingScheme, PaymentTerms, TaxingScheme, Tax1Rate, Tax2Rate, CalculateTax2OnTax1, Tax1Name, Tax2Name, TaxOnShipping, Custom1, Custom2, Custom3, ItemName, ItemDescription, ItemQuantity, ItemQuantityUoM, ItemUnitPrice, ItemDiscount, ItemSubtotal, ItemTaxCode
) VALUES (
'Yu',  'Yau ',  '01224 580318',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  'GBP',  '1',  '',  '',  '', 0, 0,  'FALSE',  '',  '',  'FALSE',  '',  '',  '',  'Vg0003',  'Apple Green', 2,  'box',  '15.5',  '0%';

MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Customer,ContactName,Phone,Email,BillingAddress1,BillingAddress2,BillingCity,Bil' at line 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Missing the closing parenthesis:

```
VALUES ( ... ) ;
            ^^^
```

Comment: lolz, eagle eye over here ^^

Comment: lol wish you are right but 41 values inserting and 41 table fields column is named

Comment: sorted after one of the values was instead, ;

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you have  missed closing bracket after value. It should properly be of the form:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table () VALUES ()");
```

Answer (score 0):

This comment is in the answer box so it will display better.  The other two answers are correct.

Problems like these will occur less often if you type your queries like this:

```
insert into yourtable 
(f1
, f2
, f3
-- etc
, f10
)
values
(v1
, v2
, v3
-- etc
, v10
)
```

It keeps all your brackets visible.  You are less likely to have an extra comma.  Also, as you are developing your query, it is easier to comment out sets of fields and values should you encounter difficulties.